# Replace NaNs in matrix with the values from the row above

Tags: matlab

If there is one NaN element per row, I would like to remove it, and replace by upper elements

```
A = [   0    0;   
        0    0;   
        1   -1;   
      nan  nan;   
        0    0;   
        0    0; 
      nan  nan;
        0    0
    ]
```

The desired output is:

```
A = [   0    0;   
        0    0;   
        1   -1;   
        1   -1;   
        0    0;   
        0    0; 
        0    0; 
        0    0
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
  i = find(isnan(A));
  A(i) = A(i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First generate a logical vector that contains a `true`, whenever one element of the row is a `NaN`. Then you can use that vector to manipulate the matrix

```
mask = any(isnan(A), 2);
A(mask, :) = A([mask(2:end); false], :);
```

An alternative approach would be

```
mask = any(isnan(A), 2);
idx = find(mask);
A(idx, :) = A(idx - 1, :);
```

**Note:** Both methods fail, if the first row contains a `NaN`. For safety you could use something like

```
if mask(1)
    %# First row contains a NaN.
    ... Do something ...
else
    ... Ordinary replacement ...
end
```